# Use promised getter in VueRouter beforeEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router, es6-promise

I have been struggling to use a `vuex.getters` which is computed from a `vuex.actions` as an `if` statement in `router.beforeEach`.

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

1. Fetch an array of objects every time user enter the site.
2. And then use `array.find()` to target the one object with the same slug according to the `router.params.id` in case user enter the site with direct url.
3. Redirect route to 404 if `router.params.id` doesn't match any slug in the object array.

**Here is my approach**

```js
const router = new VueRouter(
  {
    routes: [
      {
        path: '/list/:id',
        name: 'list'
      },
      {
        path: '/edit/:id',
        name: 'edit'
      },
      //other routes
      {
        path: '/*',
        name: '404'
      }
    ]
  }
);
```

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=>{

  if ( !store.state.lists.length ){
   // fetch Object Array when user first enter
    store.dispatch('fetchLists');

  }


  if ( to.name === 'list' || to.name === 'edit'){
    // limit route only 'list' & 'edit', preventing passing undefined params
      store.commit('cloneParams', to);

     // determine if currentMonth has a valid slug, if not go to 404
      store.getters.currentMonth.slug !== '' ? next() : next('/404');

  } else {

    next();
  }

});
```

```js
getters: {
  currentMonth(state){
    var template = {
      month: '',
      slug: '',
      data: []
    }
    var obj = template;

    if ( state.lists.length ) {

      obj = state.lists.find(current => current.slug === state.paramsID);

      if ( obj === undefined ){
        obj = template
      }
    }

    return obj;
  },
```

```js
actions: {
  fetchLists({commit}){
    axios('/lists').then(
      res=>{
        commit('storeList', res);
      }
    )
  },
```

```js
mutations: {
  storeList(state, res){
    state.lists = res.data;
  },
  cloneParams(state, to){
    state.paramsID = to.params.id;
  },
```

However, I found that the getter `currentMonth` does not update after the object array `store.state.lists` is fetched and goes to 404. Meanwhile it works perfectly fine after the `store.state.lists` is fetched and stored when user goes to next other page of this SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The route guard isn't waiting for the http request to complete before checking for the api result.  Return the promise from `fetchLists`:

```js
actions: {
fetchLists({commit}){
  return axios('/lists').then(res => {          // return the promise
    commit('storeList', res);
  })
},
```

And wait for that promise in the navigation guard:

```js
router.beforeEach(async (to, from, next) => {   // async keyword

  if ( !store.state.lists.length ){
    await store.dispatch('fetchLists');         // Waiting for the promise
  }

  if ( to.name === 'list' || to.name === 'edit'){
    // limit route only 'list' & 'edit', preventing passing undefined params
      store.commit('cloneParams', to);

     // determine if currentMonth has a valid slug, if not go to 404
      store.getters.currentMonth.slug !== '' ? next() : next('/404');

  } else {
    next();
  }

});
```